# Gremlin-python in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlinpython

I`m trying to use tinkerpop3.2.3 to conncet janusgraph0.1.1  on my centOS7, everything works fine in gremlin shell. I tried to use gremlin-python3.2.3 in python shell, it also works well. But when I moved my codes to jupyter notebook, I got RuntimeError:IOLoop is already running when excuting

g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))

So, is that possible to make gremlinpython work in jupyter notebook?
I tried both python2.7 & python3.5

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are seeing is more at the Apache TinkerPop level. JanusGraph 0.1.1 ships with TinkerPop 3.2.3, and the error you are seeing was resolved with TinkerPop 3.2.5.

The master branch of JanusGraph is already at TinkerPop 3.2.6, so it is compatible with Jupyter notebooks, but you'd have to build JanusGraph from source code. I'd expect the next release of JanusGraph to be out later this month.

Comment: Was this released?

Comment: Yes the 0.2.0 release is the latest https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/